EF Core is generating a GUID - even though it's marked as DatabaseGenerated
Using Oracle database-first and Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore provider 8.23. The column in question is the table's primary key with DEFAULT SYS_GUID() and type varchar(32).
The property in C# is defined as:
class Model
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     [Column("COLUMN_NAME")]
     public string Id { get; set; }
}

But Entity Framework Core is creating the GUID and not letting the database generate it. This results in lowercase GUIDs with dashes in them.
How can I remove this behavior and make EF Core allow the database to generate the default value? I assume this has to do with the fact that EF Core has found a property named Id and wants to fill that in with a GUID.

How do you know EF is creating any GUID for the column considering the data type is string. Marked as an Identity column EF will ignore any value written into the property when adding a new item. The field will be expected to be set by the DB and will be populated in the entity after you call SaveChanges. I would suspect you have code calling the setter somewhere. If you are encountering different behaviour then include code that reproduces the behaviour. (I.e. how you are initializing a new entity and saving, where are you seeing an ID available before SaveChanges?)

@StevePy I am logging the commands to the database and see that the parameter is included in the insert command. Additionally, as I said, oracle does not create them with dashes. I've since fixed the issue by using RAW(16) and Guid types respectively, but this is still (IMO) total horsehockey default behavior by EF.

@StevePy I've also read online, but been unable to verify, that EF will look for Key properties that match the format xyzId and automatically generate GUIDs for them. I'm doing nothing special to insert these records into the DB, and am using no GUID code anywhere. Just doing DbSet.Add and then SaveChanges

No, EF generally does not automatically generate anything for [Key], especially with DatabaseGenerated set. If it were to set a Guid value that would be a for a Guid type property, not a string. Change your ID to private string _id; public string Id { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; }}  then set a breakpoint inside the setter. See if that gets hit, if it does that should help explain what and where this might be getting set. Otherwise check if there are any custom interceptors or code on the DbContext that might be injecting values.

@AlgoRythm Your question shows a string property, not a GUID. EF doesn't generate GUIDs for string properties. You didn't post the model configuration, table schema or any code that inserts data, so it's impossible to guess why the application generates GUID strings for this string property.
